# Plot the resolvent operator function of a second order differential operator

Tags: differential-equations, scripting

I would like to plot the resolvent operator function of the following second order differential operator in $ L^1(0,+\infty)$, given by: $$(A) f(t)= \varepsilon f''(t) + b(t)f'(t)+c(t)f(t), \quad t\in (0+\infty),$$
with the following boundary conditions $\varepsilon f'(0)+b(t)f(0)=0 $ where $f\in W^{2,1}(0,+\infty)  $, $\varepsilon>0$ and $a$ and $b$ are regular bounded functions.
So, the resolvent operator is finding the function $f$ such that for all $g\in L^1(0,+\infty)$, $f$ solves the following resolvent equation:
$$ (a-A)f=g , \quad a\text{ is in the the resolvent set of } A.$$
I tried a Mathematica code to see the behaviour of this functions $f$, so it is the next:

```
g[t_] = t/(1 + t^2);
b[t_] = (6 t^2)/(1 + t^3);
c[t_] = (6 t - 18 t^4)/(1 + t^3)^2;

pNDSolveValue = 
 ParametricNDSolveValue[{-f''[t] - b[t] f'[t] + (c[t] - a) f[t] == 
    g[t], f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 1}, f[t], {t, 10}, {a}]
Plot[Evaluate@Table[pNDSolveValue[a], {a, 1, 6}], {t, 0, 10}, 
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 16] & /@ {t, f[t]}), 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[PromptForm[a, #] & /@ Range[6], Scaled[{.8, .6}]], 
 ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRange -> All]
```

What do you think of this code? Does it accurately represent my situation and my problematic? (here, the parameter is $a$ and $\varepsilon=1$) ?